# Only older version of a word file is available. How can I recover a missing newer version?

Tags: microsoft-word

I worked all day yesterday on a Word document (.doc). My habit is to save a file as I am working on it throughout the day. I even made a backup copy on my flash drive.

Today, when I went to open the file I found it available but only in an older version (both on the hard drive and flash drive). It is as if I did not work on it yesterday at all. My question is, how do I recover a newer version of a document that is missing? The document is there but only in its older form.

I searched recycling for ASD files, I attempted to find other version of the file in Word, I looked in the unsaved folder in Microsoft Office, I tried searching Windows Explorer for the document by date, but all of this has proven futile. And I know that I didn't accidentally save it under another name because I searched for the document by content as well.

Comment: What is the `Date Modified` of the document, and does it match up with then you think you would have last saved it?

Comment: Are you sure that this wasn't renamed? If you look in your Word history by selecting the 'File' > 'Recent' section, there's nothing in there? 'Newer' versions of a document won't exist because, from Windows perspective, the 'Newest' version would be the version it displays. Its very unlikely that word would just lose saved work. Are you sure you have no recovery options when you opened Word for the first time today?

Comment: I worked on it yesterday (January 19), but the date modified is listed as January 18. 

I am quite certain it wasn't renamed because I remember a few unique phrases that I used and I searched for those. No document matches them. Unfortunately I cannot there is nothing available for me in the "recent" section because I did quite a bit of work on other files before I realized I had this problem. 

As for recovery options, everything online shows me how to search for older versions. I'm puzzled as to how I lost a newer one.

Answer (score 2):

There are four basic possibilities - (1) It went somewhere else (in another directory), or (2) It got a different name, or (3) It never saved for some reason, or (4) You accidentally copied the wrong way around (old one from flash drive over new one on hard disk).

(3) means it's gone. (4) means you could try to search with low-level programs through your hard disk for remainders of it, but chances are *very* low to find anything at all, not to speak of finding a functioning document; especially as you say you did lots of other things.
(1) and (2) should be easy; search your complete hard disk for *.doc* (in Explorer), and sort by last change date.

My recommendation is try that search, and if you don't find it, bite the bullet and start to rewrite it. Anything else cost you many many hours and has very little chance.

Comment: Thank you, Aganju. 

I went through all of those options and believe it was number 4. I got a tech from work to look at it and even installed an "undelete" program, but it was a lost cause. It looks like once you copy an older document on top of a newer one, going back "to the future" so to speak, is no longer possible. 

I appreciate your kind words. I'm moving on and re-writing it today. Thanks!